# Turning list into a data.frame

Tags: r

```
mylist <- list(structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")), structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H")))

mylist
[[1]]
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
 1  1  2  2  2  2 NA NA 

[[2]]
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
 1  1  1  1  1  2  1 NA
```

I have a list like above and I want to collapse it into a data.frame so that I can subset each column individually ie `df$A`, `df$B`, etc.

```
> df$A
[1] 1 1

> df$B
[1] 1 1

> df$C
[1] 2 1
```

And so forth

Comment: I think you want `do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, as.data.frame.list))`

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Actually, with this one since you've got all numeric values you could do `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mylist))`

Comment: @RichScriven, I'm working with data that is already a list of dataframes (`list_of_dataframes`) and modified your code as follows: `do.call(rbind, list_of_dataframes)`. This worked but created funky row names. To avoid creating row names I used this code `do.call(function(...) rbind(..., make.row.names = FALSE), list_of_dataframes)`. For my simple test case this worked (no runky row names) but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate use of `...`. Is this a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `unlist` and the `split` according to the names, something like

```
temp <- unlist(mylist)
res <- split(unname(temp), names(temp))

# res$A
# [1] 1 1
# res$B
# [1] 1 1
# res$C
# [1] 2 1
```